# Difference between "объединяйтесь" and "соединяйтесь"?

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова, лексикон

### Background

I recently saw a translation of the well-known motto "Workers of the world, unite!", but when I looked into it, I found out that there are at least two possible translations:

1. Пролетарии всех стран, соединяйтесь!
2. Пролетарии всех стран, объединяйтесь!

### What I found

Now I know that the literal translation of those sentences is "Workers of all countries" for the first part. What I'm unsure about is how the respective last words differ in meaning. For "соединяйтесь" I found the meanings "connect, combine, incorporate". For "объединяйтесь" I found "unite, integrate, consolidate", which seems to be more in line with the English version.

### Question

Are the two words exchangeable or do they convey slightly different things?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the modern language, *соединяться* means "to connect".

In the past, *соединяться* was used in several different meanings which are now expressed by the other words:

1. "To unite". In the modern language, *объединяться*:

   > - После того великое княжество Литовское иногда существовало отдельно, но чаще соединялось с Польшею под властью одного короля
   > - Землевладельцы для этого соединялись в определенные товарищества, или «кумпанства»
   > - Персы начали соединяться в большие партии для совместного возвращения на родину
2. "To combine with, to be accompanied with". In the modern language, *сочетаться* or *сопрягаться*:

   > - Подвиг, соединяясь с благодарностью, называется уже службой
   > - Но вначале пышность костюмов редко соединялась с изяществом и вкусом
   > - … в ней одновременно соединялись почтительность с насмешкой и глупость с плутовством
3. "To gather". In the modern language, *собираться*:

   > - Дом её был самый модный. У ней соединялось лучшее парижское общество
   > - В университете соединялись люди всех свободных состояний (крепостные же не допускались)
   > - Когда-то, вспомнилось мне, здесь, в этих стенах, соединялись все художественные русские силы
4. "To merge". In the modern language, *сливаться*:

   > - Сколько я себя помню, представление о Михаиле Петровиче как профессоре всегда соединялось в моих мыслях с его издательскою деятельностью как журналиста
   > - ― Для Саво-ойского?! ― изумленно переспросили собеседники, в воображении которых с понятием о Савойском доме соединялось представление о Викторе-Эммануиле, о Кавуре, о Гарибальди и даже о Мадзини.
5. "To communicate (as in vessels)". In the modern language, *сообщаться*:

   > - Я натолкнулся на новое озеро, с которым соединялась промоина
   > - Широким руслом, разливающимся по плоской равнине, соединяется он с Щугором с правой стороны
6. "To associate". In the modern language, *ассоциироваться*:

   > - Но до настоящего времени с именем Грановского соединяется для студента все светлое и привлекательное
   > - … и он помнил хорошо, что с этим именем соединяется что-то особенное и очень негодное
   > - Ни слова жалобы, ни прощаний и слез, ни утешений и завещаний ― ничего, что соединяется с представлением о смерти

All these words are not new and have been used in almost the same senses in the past, synonymously with *соединяться*. But by now, they have almost completely replaced the latter in their respective meanings.

*Пролетарии всех стран, соединяйтесь!* is a line from The Communist Manifesto, first translated into Russian in 1869, which had been since fossilized in its current form. Had this translation been first made these days, this line would have probably been *Пролетарии всех стран, объединяйтесь!*

The same stands for the Russian names of the United States and the United Kingdom: *Соединённые Штаты* and *Соединённое Королевство*. Now it would sooner be *Объединённые Штаты* and *Объединённое Королевство*, same as *Объединённые Арабские Эмираты*.

Answer (score 3):

Though you have correctly noticed that the word "соединять" is used when you're talking about connecting or combining several parts of something, while "объединять" is more about uniting, both words are synonyms and their usage fields are largely overlapped.

Notice, for example, how *the United Arab Emirates* is called *Объединенные Арабские Эмираты* in Russian, while *the United States* is called *Соединенные Штаты Америки*. In both cases we're talking about something united, but we have both words used for conveying the same meaning.

Answer (score 3):

Those two words are very close (and in my opinion you've translated them correctly) but not interchangeable in many contexts. In many scenarios "объединять" is more about collective effort, you can say "эти два отдела должны объединить свои усилия" but it'll be quite unidiomatic to say "эти два отдела должны соединить свои усилия".

There's also an idiom "соединиться в [любовном] экстазе" and other phrases where "соединиться" is about emotional connecting like "соединиться со своей второй половинкой".

I'd rather say that "соединять/соединяться" in some subtle cases is more about taking heterogenous entities and making them on some level of abstraction a single entity, while "объединять" is about combining such separate entities but not necessarily losing them as separate entities.

Again, just like in many of such cases I'd rather recommend to take notice how and in what context these words are used exactly and to just memorize and use exactly that form.

Answer (score 0):

A simplier understanding could come from:

"объединяйтесь" to do something together,

"соединяйтесь" to be something together.

Answer (score -2):

Объединяйтесь = unite

Соединяйтесь = connect